# ¿Cómo reemplazo el mismo renglón de varios archivos de texto por un renglón constante ya definido?

Tags: python, script, txt, replace

gracias de antemano por tomarte el tiempo de leerme, necesito reemplazar el mismo renglon de muchos archivos de texto por un texto ya definido, el renglon que necesito reemplazar tiene la palabra "define" comun en todos los archivos,asi como tambien es el renglon numero 15 en todos los archivos, me pudieran ayudar dandonde un norte de como realizar está actividad, relativamente soy novato en phyton. muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Ten presente que [es.so] no es un sitio de tutoriales ni de orientaciones. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: De antemano, te aviso que no existe una solución que no implique la reescritura de todo el archivo. Si querés una respuesta detallada, te recomiendo agregar tu intento de resolver el problema (sea código que no haya funcionado o una lista de links visitados que no sirvieron como solución)